# Comando "git status" não mostra os arquivos alterados dentro das pastas

Tags: git

A estrutura da minha pasta é esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu alterar(sem editar o código) algum arquivo dentro de alguma dessas pastas(Calculadora,caraCoroa, etc), quando eu rodo `git status` ele não lista nenhum arquivo modificado, por quê isso ocorre ?
Por exemplo se eu rodar `cd Calculadora/android && gradlew clean` ele vai modificar alguns arquivos do projeto e se em seguida eu rodar `git status` ele não lista nenhum arquivo modificado, porém se alterar alguma linha de código ele mostra o arquivo modificado.

Comment: Os arquivos modificados por `gradlew clean` não estão ignorados?

Comment: Como está o conteúdo do arquivo `.gitignore`? Tanto do projeto quanto da pasta em que a mudança supostamente não aparece?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, o .gitignore gerado automaticamente por react-native init estava ignorando estes arquivos,

Comment: @LINQ, como descobriu o problema do AP, o que acha de fornecer uma resposta para a pergunta? :)